# Mac Outlook 15.11 2015 "connection to the server failed or was dropped" (Error # -3253)

Tags: macos, email, ms-office

In Outlook 15.11 2015 on Mavericks, I am constantly getting a "connection to the server failed or was dropped (Error # -3253)" for my pop accounts when I send/receive. I can send mail, but not receive it. I use GoDaddy as a hosting service. I have tried deleting the account, as well as the profile under profile manager. Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, do you have a solution? I see on the [MS forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macofficeo365-macoutlook/after-latest-outlook-1511-update-pop-email-account/62f4f9d2-6f3e-4ea4-b0b6-757e523eaac4) where this is an issue, but I don't see a resolution.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem as well - oddly, only on my personal user account. On my work account, everything works fine. Like you I can't find help anywhere.

Comment: I get this sae error soon as i installed outlook 2016, i can send mail but not receive with my pop3 account. If i Use Apple Mail, I can send and receive perfectly. I'm Using El Capitan. Wish I didn't install office 2016, i find it sluggish compared to 2011.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, too, and about the same time Safari started acting up by not loading pages. I found that the problem was the Avast Anti-Virus Software that I had installed on my machine. Once it was removed, the problem was solved: no more Safari issues and no more Outlook issues, specifically Error -3253.

Comment: I believe that it's not going to be every security software, mostly I think it's the features that block and monitor incoming and outgoing traffic to your machine. Such as "Web Monitor" or "Email Monitor".